# schedulable class has jobs pending or in progress error

Tags: class, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

I am trying to update a class which is throwing the following error
This schedulable class has jobs pending or in progress

I have already deleted the scheduler for the class but  it is throwing the same error.

There are no processing jobs Is there anyway to resolver this?

Or is there any way to bulk abort all jobs?

Comment: Is this in a Sandbox? If so, you may need to open a case with support.

Answer (score 2):

You could abort jobs through apex if you know how to filter them.  See this for how to do it by name: http://www.crmscience.com/single-post/2015/08/15/How-to-Abort-a-Scheduled-Queued-Apex-Job-by-Name

```
// loop through jobs located by name that we need to abort
for(CronTrigger ct : [SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Name, CronJobDetail.JobType
                    FROM CronTrigger
                   WHERE CronJobDetail.Name like 'Work Order%']){

  // abort the job, try/catch because the job might not exist
  // if it's being aborted manually or from another execution
  try{
    system.abortJob(ct.id);
  } catch (exception e) {}
}
```

If it's still not helpful with this, then salesforce support is the next step like @sfdcfox said